# How to find unused functions in powershell

Tags: powershell

In powershell, is there any way to find out the unused functions?

By [ScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) I can find the unused variables, but not upto the function level.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question really fits to SO but you could take a look at this: [Powershell CodeManager](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-CodeManager-v6-d4592fee/view/Reviews)

Comment: VS Code also lists the amount of uses and links to the calls.